# Django Boolean Queryset Filter Not Working

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite, django-queryset

This has been frustrating me for the better part of an hour.

I have the following model:

```
sold= models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And the following view code:

```
properties = Property.objects.filter(sold=False).order_by('-created_on');
```

And the following values in my sqlite3 database:

```
 sqlite> select sold from clients_property;
1
1
1
1
1
```

And the following template code DOES work (as in, hides the sold items):

```
{% if not property.sold %}
```

Anyone know why the query set filter isn't working or why I'm doing it wrong?  I've tried:

```
sold="1"
sold=1
sold="false"
sold=False
sold="False"
```

Comment: How did you insert the data into your database?  A value of `1` commonly evaluates to `True`.  So it looks to me like the data in your database is corrupt.

Comment: sold=False is the correct filter, it just looks like you dont have any properties with sold=False in your database.

Comment: I inserted it using python with the variable of sold=False

Comment: Also, I manually updated via the SQLite3 shell to both the integer 0 and 1, and changed the filter statement in the view to both sold='1' and sold=1 and none of that changed the results.

Comment: Sigh.  OK.  This is going to go down as one of the most idiotic Stackoverflow questions ever, but with Textmate I was editing another view than the one I was viewing via the webapp.  Everything works perfectly and I'm truly sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Well, your "idiotic" question *did* help me find my problem, though :-) See Kiril's answer as sqlite has some weirdness with having both False and zero, but not both meaning false...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From what you've posted, everything is working as advertised. If you try this stuff from the shell, you should get the following results. Of course I'm making some of it up, so read before you just copy-paste.

```
>>> from myapp.models import Property
>>> Property.objects.all()
[<Property: Property object>,<Property: Property object>,<Property: Property object>,<Property: Property object>,<Property: Property object>,]
>>> Property.objects.filter(sold=False)
[]
>>> Property.objects.filter(sold=True)
[<Property: Property object>,<Property: Property object>,<Property: Property object>,<Property: Property object>,<Property: Property object>,]
>>> Property.objects.create(sold=False, my='other', fields=1)
>>> Property.objects.filter(sold=False)
[<Property: Property object>,]
```

Jack is right, 1 should evaluate to True in most SQL implementations.

Answer (score 23):

This has happened to me as well.

Turned out in SQLite you can have Boolean with value 0 and Boolean with value False.

So Django does not work with the ones set to False.

I saw this discrepancy in SQLiteMan.

Simple update fixed the problem.

I think this happened during schema upgrades and migration in my dev environment, so I am not too worried about it.

Comment: I just had precisely the same problem, and this fixed it.  I used South to add a database column through a migration, and then all of a sudden Django didn't know how to handle it when filtering.  I updated all my "False" to 0, and everything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  My solution was to change the type of the column from a 'bit' to a 'tinyint'.

The issue in my case was caused by a manually added column in a table.