# Django queryset filter on boolean not working

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    order_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I added this field to my development mysqllite db manually since its a new field for a model/table that already existed. I then tried:

```
mymodel.objects.filter(order_closed=False) #and with True
```

and its producing incorrect or unpredictable results. I saw some mention that is could be a sqllite thing but I'm not sure? The templates seem to understand whether its a true or false value but python code doesn't. To clarify with some examples:

{{mymodel.order_closed}} will print 0 after I set the default to 0 in sqllite. but using .filter(order_closed=value) will still return every record.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933196/django-boolean-queryset-filter-not-working

Comment: I advice you don't use sqlite even as development database. Sqlite is too "mild". For example, if you create CharField(max_length=20), sqlite allows you to write 30 or 100 symbols. When you'll start migrating to PostgreSQL or MySQL, you'll have a problems.

Comment: When you say you 'added it manually' it sounds like you've been writing SQL. I don't think you want to do that. Try deleting the field then use python manage.py syncdb to create it (syncdb will create it from your model). See if that sorts it out.

Comment: Check the values in your db. When you add a new field it doesn't set the "default" value to the older objects in your db. So they might be "null" and not "False"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you make some mistake in wrirting SQL . If you have db which have some important informations use

```
south
```

http://south.aeracode.org/

When you will have it you can easly upgrate/edit your database .

If you dont wanna install new 'plugins' try that .
1. Delete this field from DB manualy .
2. write : python manage.py sql 'name of app'

It will return the CREATE TABLE SQL statements for the app.

Then you can upr your database manualy with some of CReate command.