# Refactoring a Django Boolean query

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a generic [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) for a `Family` object. Each `Family` has a one-to-one field with an `employee_user` and a `partner_user`, which in turn have one-to-one fields with a `Profile` model (with a related name `user_profile`) which has a Boolean `using_app` field. A family is considered to be using the app if either the employee or the partner is using the app.

Currently, I have the following [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    if app:
        using_app = app == 't'
        if using_app:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(employee_user__user_profile__using_app=using_app) |
                Q(partner_user__user_profile__using_app=using_app))
        else:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(employee_user__user_profile__using_app=using_app) &
                Q(partner_user__user_profile__using_app=using_app))

    return queryset
```

This makes this `ListView` pass the following tests (using `factory_boy` test fixtures):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from dashboard.tests.utils import AccountMixin
from lucy_web.test_factories import FamilyFactory, UserFactory


class FamilyUsingAppTest(AccountMixin, TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.login_user(UserFactory(is_superuser=True))

    def test_filter_families_using_app(self):
        family = FamilyFactory(
            employee_user=UserFactory(user_profile__using_app=True),
            partner_user=UserFactory(user_profile__using_app=False))

        self.assertIs(family.using_app, True)

        response = self.client.get(
            path=reverse('dashboard:families'),
            data={'app': 't'})

        self.assertEqual(response.context['object_list'].count(), 1)
        self.assertTrue(response.context['object_list'].first() == family)

    def test_filter_families_not_using_app(self):
        family = FamilyFactory(
            employee_user=UserFactory(user_profile__using_app=True),
            partner_user=UserFactory(user_profile__using_app=False))

        response = self.client.get(
            path=reverse('dashboard:families'),
            data={'app': 'f'})

        self.assertEqual(response.context['object_list'].count(), 0)
```

However, the `get_queryset` method contains some code repetition in the `if... else` clauses, and I'm looking to refactor it, for example by using [`Queryset.annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation). From [Django Boolean Queryset Filter Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933196/django-boolean-queryset-filter-not-working), however, I wasn't able to find a concise way to do this. Any suggestions on how to refactor this code while still passing these tests?

Comment: I was trained “Three strikes, refactor.” I see both in your view and test repetitions that happen twice. Are you going to use them more? Otherwise it’s a lot of effort that might not pay off in the end.